# Why is my attempt to get the rows from an SQL query into a global variable within my script only giving me an empty array?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to connect to a MYSQL database and grab all the email addresses in a table. I am using promises and I've tried to set a global array that would ultimately contain the addresses. However, after running my code, it's empty. My code is:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');
function DBconnect(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(
            mysql.createConnection({
                        host:"0.0.0.0",
                        user: "mysqldbadmin",
                        password: "mypassword",
                        database: "myDB"
                    })
        )
    })

}

var emailArr = new Array(); //winds up empty, should not be
DBconnect().then(result =>{

    var validUsers = new Array();
    result.connect(function(err){
                   if (err){
                    throw err;
                   }
                   result.query(" select users_email from site_users left join site_usermeta on ( site_users.id = site_usermeta.user_id) where (meta_value LIKE '%spec1%' OR meta_value LIKE '%spec2%') and meta_key=\"site_capabilities\" ",
                    function(err, res, fields){
                           if(err)
                               throw err;

                               var i = 0;
                               for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
                                   validUsers[i] = res[i].users_email;

                               }
                            console.log(validUsers); // THIS prints out what I need
                            emailArr = validUsers;

                         result.end(function(err){});
                       });

                   })
})
console.log(emailArr);
```

I need `emailArr` to hold the string values; I'm going to need them later in my script. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Because your log statement executes before the data has come back from the database. Your database connection and query are being done asynchronously.

Try putting `console.log(emailArr);` after `emailArr = validUsers;`. You will see that it has the value you put inside it.